# Inserting into a linked list not working properly

Tags: c

I want to add a insert method for my linked list that would insert onto what's already in the linked list (append values).

Here's my code now:

```
struct node {
   char value;
   struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node item;

void main() {
    InsertChar('a');
    InsertChar('b');
    InsertChar('c');
}

void InsertChar(char s) {
    item *curr, *head;

    head = NULL;

    curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    curr->value = s;
    curr->next = head;
    head = curr;

    while(curr) {
        printf("%c", curr->value);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The problem is that in the console it prints

```
a 
b
c
```

I need it to print something more like

```
a
ab
abc
```

After calling the 3 InsertChar methods in main().

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be keeping track of the head of your list. E.g.:

```
struct node {
   char value;
   struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node item;

item* head = NULL;
item* curr = NULL;

void InsertChar(char s) {

    item* c = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    c->value = s;
    c->next = NULL;

    if (head)
        curr->next = c;
    else
        head = c;

    curr = c;

    for (c = head; c; c = c->next)
        printf("%c", c->value);

    printf("\n");
}

void main() {
    InsertChar('a');
    InsertChar('b');
    InsertChar('c');
}
```

This outputs:

```
a
ab
abc
```

Comment: Works. :) Additionally, how would I get the length of this linked list? What variable would I loop?

Comment: Create a global variable n, initialize it to 0 and then increment it inside InsertChar(). Alternatively, do the same in the printf loop. Please, mark the answer as "correct" if the solution worked for you.

Comment: What if I wanted a completely different method for checking the length? What variable would I use? Also, I marked your answer as correct.

Comment: int len() { int n; item* c; for (n=0, c=head; c; c=c->next, n++); return n; }

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the head is declared locally in the function, and when you leave the function, you loose it.  When you come to the function again, you create it from scratch, etc.

So you need to pass head as an argument to your InsertChar function.

Also, if you want to see a, ab, abc output, you need to add elements to the tail of your list, rather than to the head as you do it now.  In order to achieve that, you either need to store a separate pointer for tail or every time traverse to the last element.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems :

1. The list's is redefined each time the function is invoked.
2. you should start from the head of the list when you access the list's elements

This should fix your problem :

```
struct node {
   char value;
   struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node item;

item * head = NULL; // global 

void main() {
    InsertChar('a');
    InsertChar('b');
    InsertChar('c');
}

void InsertChar(char s) {
    item *curr, *temp;

    curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    curr->value = s;
    curr->next = head;
    head = curr;
    temp = head;

    while(temp) {
        printf("%c", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, now the console spams `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...` without stopping. :/

Comment: Sorry, there was an error. I did not assign correctly a pointer in the loop. I did not tried the code. Now, it should work. Give it a try.